# Where are log files when using Spring with built-in Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, logging

My company uses Spring to provide RESTful service, But I can't find the log files as I usually do(from Tomcat/logs).All I can find is a jar file when Tomcat is built-in. So how can I find the log files?

Comment: you got the solution?

Comment: @Vinoth No.I decide to turn it to a war package.

Answer (score 0):

Following Link will Help you Just check it

http://tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm